# Most popular screen resolutions / ratios among android tablets and smarthphones

Tags: android, layout, resolution, tablet, smartphone

I am looking for a site that offer statistics/graphs providing most popular resolutions / screen ratios on android smartphones and tablets. Need it to design the UI and plan how to scale. Would be cool if someone shared the data.

Comment: For most apps, if you are worrying about "resolutions / screen ratios", you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

- http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The asker asked for a chart or graph of the most common screen resolutions. The first link you sent is pixel densities (not resolution size), and the second doesn't show usage statistics nor does it have graphs comparing them. I'm a UI designer also and am looking for the same thing in the original question.

Answer (score 5):

Resolution stats from the Unity 3D engine:

http://stats.unity3d.com/mobile/display-android.html

Comment: Numbers look fishy. Don't trust it since it contains no source reference.

Comment: Unity seem to be far and away the market leader for game engines on mobile.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use Android's official : http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

EDIT: Take a look also at : http://opensignal.com/reports/fragmentation.php But pay attention it's based on analysis of a single app and not the entire android users (there's no full scale analysis of that...)

Comment: I already shared that link with him, but it seems that's not what he's looking for.